# Application development on various devices

Tags: architecture, software-design, processor

My client wants application development for a particular device. But I have no idea how to begin and which technology that device will support.

I want to know about the devices and their support to programming languages. Is it possible to develop on any device with any technology.

You can give me link, name of book or whatever that contains information on this, I am happy to read. I searched the internet but can't get anything.

I am a Java developer and don't know where to post this. Advance thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quite broad question.

Without any technology it can be hard. It would be nice to know which programming languages are supported. If you know this, you could already start.

Make all O.S. calls in a separate library so you can later connect them to the known O.S.

However, I suggest you first make a design document, or even better, an architecture document... and to make that you need to have some answers and you can make well thought decisions what programming language and design decisions really to use.

If you don't know anything about the technologies to be used, also you can start writing the manual if that is applicable, or think about testing etc.

Implementation can come later.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So what I get is every device doesn't support every language, it depends on OS we are using right?

Comment: True, e.g. Windows supports normally C#, Apple supports iOS, C++ and Java are normally supported by multiple platforms. But every  language has their pros and cons, which depend on the type of application you want to make, and if there is some possible future change of device types.